# Recognizing keys of piano on the image

Tags: image-processing

I am newbie in image processing, so sorry if it will seem dumb to you.

I am building app that will show user the keys that he/she must press.
I want to recognize the keys on piano.

How can I achieve this? What can you advise me(tutorials, online courses)?

[image]

Comment: Wow, there is a lot to learn then! You are saying: Hey, I am new to mechanical engineering, can you help me building a car? There are a lot of things to do between starting and building a car! Start with some Matlab or openCV tutorials, learn a bit what algoritms are there and build some understanding in your head! Its a hard task what you are asking

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I am pleased that you replied to me. I understand that is very difficult. Nevertheless, thanks :)

Comment: Please explain a bit more about why you need to recognise the keys - surely if you are showing the user which keys they must press, you don't need to `recognise` the keys but `depict` the correct keys depressed in the correct sequence with the correct timings. Or are you planning to video the person's hands or somesuch?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, this application will work on smart glass(real piano). Application will show which keys must press to play for example the composition of Beethoven

Comment: Do you mean Xbox Smart Glass?

Comment: No, Epson Smart glasses

Answer (score 1):

Try openCV tutorials, it is free and well documented. Just read all and think how can you use this feature for your task. Spend 1-2 month, and ask here again but more distinctly, like: I use binarization and morphology operations and Hough line detectors but now I have this problem...

You may use terms "binarization", "morphology operations" and  "Hough line detector" as a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of recognizing all keys, try something simpler that wiil just do.

For instance recognizing the piano as a whole would be enough I presume. Just ask the user to press C key then each time one octave upper C or whatever. It would be easy to divide 7, the distance between the two keys, even on 2D image of 3D perspective.